# Docusign REST API template field overriding pdf field

Tags: json, rest, pdf, docusignapi

I'm working with the Docusign Rest API and I'm running into issues with merging pdf fields and Docusign template fields. I have a pdf being sent through Docusign that contains the same field as it's corresponding template. That is working fine, but the issue is when I have filled out information on the pdf.

When the signer gets the envelope, the template places it's text box, check box, signature, etc. over the pdf fields that were filled out. What I would like is to have those pdf fields prevent Docusign from placing those template fields over pre-filled fields in the pdf. Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

If more information is required, let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your issue is, can you elaborate a little further?  It seems you're saying that if you let the DocuSign service convert your PDF fields into DocuSign tabs, that you lose the pre-filled data in those fields?  If that's the case, have you tried saving the values that you don't want to lose, adding the document to an envelope and letting the system apply your template, then once created use an api call to populate the values you saved?

Comment: @Ergin I was thinking about possibly doing it that way, but I was hoping there was something more simple that I could do. Here's a scenario of the problem I want to solve. I have a pdf field where the user fills in their name. The user sends the pdf through DocuSign and it matches a template, so the template should have the data of that field already in that place, or better yet, lock the information from the pdf there and disallow any information from being placed in that text box field provided by the DocuSign template.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution provided through the above comments, I believe you should be able to get this working just using the form fields.  Take a look at the **Document Parameters** section of the REST API v2 Guide starting on page 100:

http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf

If you look at the `transformPdfFields` property of the request you'll see that it states several aspects about form field conversion:

---

**Transform PDF Fields**

Only the FieldTypes and FieldProperties listed below are extrapolated from the forms:

*FieldTypes* that are extrapolated are: CheckBox, DateTime, ListBox, Numeric, Radio, Text, Signature, and Password.

*FieldProperties* that are extrapolated are: ReadOnly, Required, MaxLength, Positions, and **Initial Data**.